# paternity test in Germany

Tags: germany, family-law

I heard that in order to make a paternity test in Germany, the consent of both spouses is needed. If the husband has doubts about whether he is the father of a child born in wedlock, can he insist on such a test in order to avoid paying child support in the event of a divorce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, a father can contest [paternity](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p5506)

A man married to the mother at the time of birth is legally the father. He has 2 years to contest this in court. Without going into details, the court has the power to order a paternity test if necessary.

Comment: The important part is that he has to go through court. He can't just send a sample to a lab for testing without consent of the mother. If the child is not a minor, they would also have to agree to a paternity test that hasn't been mandated by court.